How C variable usage changes its memory address?
This code shows that b variable is placed right after a variable:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    a=15;
    b=2654;
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    &a;
    printf("%d %d\n", a, *(&b-1));
}

Outputs
15 2654
15 15

But when I delete &a; b is no longer right after a:
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    a=15;
    b=2654;
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, *(&b-1));
}

Outputs
15 2654
15 21927

Why when I don't get address of a variable then a and b aren't placed near each other? Is it related to compiler optimization?

Even forming your &b-1 pointer is undefined behaviour, let alone dereferencing it with *(&b-1). The code only happens to show what you expect, given that everything does something. And the compiler may order variables anyhow it chooses, so your expectation is suspect anyway. So you are wasting your time trying to analyse why it doesn't work.

Probably register allocation. Since the address of a is never taken, its perfectly reasonable for the compiler to put it in a register.
It's also perfectly reasonable on such a short function for the compiler to simply delete a altogether and pass a constant to printf.
In general you can't do this; on larger functions the compiler tends to use hash objects in memory allocation; resulting in no discernible relation between variable declaration order and variable order on the stack.

*(&b-1) invokes undefined behavior, since you are doing pointer arithmetic outside valid allocated space.
Dissecting your code using gcc 14 x86_64 -O3, then the first printf statement results in code generated as:
mov     edx, 2654
mov     esi, 15
...
call    printf

That is, both a and b where stored in registers.
That you happened to use &a later does not matter since that line is a no-op with no side effects. In my case compiling under -O3, then adding/removing that line had no effect. Just taking the variable's address doesn't mean anything (except it would have been invalid code in case you declared it as register int a;... but you didn't, leaving it to the compiler to declare it as it pleases.)
Then further down in the same code, the second printf statement was generated as:
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]
mov     esi, 15

That is, for b the compiler goes to fetch some value at an 8 byte offset on the stack. But neither a nor b were declared on the stack to begin with... Weirdness like this in the code generation itself may happen when you have undefined behavior bugs.
